# How to fix it: iOS twice upload file to dropbox

Tags: ios, upload, dropbox-api

I have upload files to Dropbox in my iOS app. I have created a thread for every file and when I test a big folder include 1255 files upload to Dropbox, I found that a file has upload twice. The file name is `19_Ps_CHM-CHS_119 (1).mp3` and `19_Ps_CHM-CHS_119.mp3`.

I have try to upload again when `error.code` is -1001 or -1003 or -1005 in:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error{  .....}
```

I think I lost Internet connection and recieved error while finished in server, so I will reupload and Dropbox server has saved.

Any idea for me?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the size of your mp3 file. However some Dropbox Api's have a problem with big file sizes. 
Here for example [here](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/T_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesRoutes.htm) is written that the size should not be bigger than 150 MB.
So check the size and if your file already exsists in your cloud and if it is playable (Uploaded twice correctly). In addition add which Api version you are using.

Comment: Thanks,  upload mp3 is only 1-3M for each file. and I have found out way to do,  that check uploaded file name in dropbox upload delegate, my app will remove item if return a different file name. I think it is OK.